# Monitoring based on spring actuator best practices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

In my latest project we have spring actuator used for checking a health of the application. For the moment we are using only one default feature of the actuator (health endpoint).
I think we can do much better there and I have a question about best practices for monitoring build upon on spring actuator.

Can someone share experience related to this topic?

Best regards.